# How to do mappings in Oracle DB efficiently?

Tags: oracle, mapping

I need to map records in oracle to my data source file to target fields, please see below:
[image: mappings]
The mapping should take place only when all the fields are matched together on the left hand side of the picture to the right hand side, all other records should stay as is. I have a file with 10m records that needs to be treated. What is the most efficient way/query to produce  a target file ?

Thanks so much

Comment: Please describe more clear your situation. Do you have *files* or *tables*. To map on *equal condition* check the keyword `database join`.

Comment: Thank you. I have files that will load in the two tables, which kind of join?

Comment: Asan  alternative to file load you may use *external tables*. Use `left ouer join` from the *source* table to the *lookup* table using *equal* predicate on all column used for the mapping. This will preserve the not mapped rows with *null vales*. You must ensure that in the mapping table the keys build a `primary key` (i.e. unique and not null).

Comment: Thank you Asan! thats what I will do. Can you please share a line with the select statement, I need all other lines as is and only the mapped ones with the target values instead